# Validação de campos Jquery/Ajax/PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validação

Li algumas perguntas aqui no soPT, mas não encontrei o que queria. fiz uma validação básica com ajax e jquery que está funcionando, porém tem um imprevisto.
São dois campos: **email** e **time**.

## HTML

```
 <p><div class="input-group">
         <span class="inreg input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true" id="basic-addon1"></span>
         <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control cartolaInput2" placeholder="Email" name="email" required aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
       </div></p>
 <p> <div class="input-group">
        <span class="inreg input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true" id="basic-addon1"></span>
        <input type="text" id="time" class="form-control cartolaInput2" placeholder="Nome do seu Clube" maxlength="30" name="time" required aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div><p style="font-family:cartolaiff-light;font-size: 12px;color: #666;width:80%"><i>*Este é o nome que ficará em exibição para os outros jogadores! Escolha qualquer nome, sem restrições, desde que não esteja em uso!</i></p></p>

     <div class="botoes" style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
       <input type="submit" id="confirmar" value="Enviar!"  class="botao-confirmar"/>
     </div>
```

## jQuery/ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#email").on("keyup", function() {
          $.ajax({
              context: 'this',
              dataType: 'html',
              url: "./componentes/email.php",
              type: "post",
              data: ({
                  email: $("#email").val()
              }),
              success: function(respostae) {
                  if (respostae == "sim") {
                      $("#email").css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#email").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#email").parent().find('span').css('color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', false);
                      $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '1');
                  } else {
                      $("#email").css('border-color', 'red');
                      $("#email").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'red');
                      $("#email").parent().find('span').css('color', 'red');
                      $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', true);
                      $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '0.5');
                  }
              }
          });
      });


      $("#time").on("keyup", function() {
          $.ajax({
              context: 'this',
              dataType: 'html',
              url: "./componentes/nomet.php",
              type: "post",
              data: ({
                  time: $("#time").val()
              }),
              success: function(respostat) {
                  if (respostat == "sim") {
                      $("#time").css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#time").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#time").parent().find('span').css('color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                      $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', false);
                      $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '1');
                  } else {
                      $("#time").css('border-color', 'red');
                      $("#time").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'red');
                      $("#time").parent().find('span').css('color', 'red');
                      $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', true);
                      $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '0.5');
                  }
              }
          });
      });

  });
```

Os códigos php não serão importantes, pois já funcionam, por isso não os coloquei.

O que acontece é que, se o ***email*** inserido pelo usuário **já existir**, o campo **email** ficará **vermelho** e o botão confirmar ficará **desativado** *(Até aí, tudo bem)*. Porém, se eu colocar o **time** e a validação for **ok** (ou seja, não ter nenhum time com o mesmo nome) o botão para confirmar ficará **disponível** novamente

Não consegui pensar em algo para solucionar. Essa é apenas uma validação primária (faço a validação no php também e está 100%), mas queria esta validação pois fica mais fácil para os usuários.

Comment: Cara cria um campo hidden  e usa como flag sempre que já que o retorno do ajax for que já existi você flaga ele como 1, ai toda vez que o retornar algo do ajax você verifica ele(assim vc vai saber que mesmo que não existe o time já existe o e-mail então o botão deve continuar indisponivel)

Comment: Tentarei. Jajá posto resultados

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a sua função `keyup` validar os dois, chamando ambos os ajax e assim validando como você deseja.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").on("keyup", function() {
        $.ajax({
            context: 'this',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "./componentes/email.php",
            type: "post",
            data: ({
                email: $("#email").val()
            }),
            success: function(respostae) {
                if (respostae == "sim") {

                    $.ajax({
                        context: 'this',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: "./componentes/nomet.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: ({
                            time: $("#time").val()
                        }),
                        success: function(respostat) {
                            if (respostat == "sim") {
                                $("#time").css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                                $("#time").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                                $("#time").parent().find('span').css('color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');

                                $("#email").css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                                $("#email").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');
                                $("#email").parent().find('span').css('color', 'rgb(38, 202, 94)');

                                $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', false);
                                $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '1');
                            } else {
                                $("#time").css('border-color', 'red');
                                $("#time").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'red');
                                $("#time").parent().find('span').css('color', 'red');
                                $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', true);
                                $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '0.5');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#email").css('border-color', 'red');
                    $("#email").parent().find('span').css('border-color', 'red');
                    $("#email").parent().find('span').css('color', 'red');
                    $("#confirmar").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("#confirmar").css('opacity', '0.5');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

E aí você faria isso para ambas as funções `keyup`

Comment: Olá. Dessa forma não funcionaria. A validação é feita enquanto o usuário digita, por isso o "keyup"

Comment: Eu entendo, mas não é possível validar os 2, enquanto o usuário digita? Se o usuário estiver digitando o email primeiro e o time estiver vazio, no php do time, retorna falso. Ou então passar a validação para o submit do formulário.

Comment: Não tinha pensado. Vou tentar, já comento o resultado